# Trying to port a tensorflow python to javascript

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to port this python code to javascript, I'm getting very different results in my js script so I wanted to make sure that my **dense layers** are correct:

### Python

```
let trainValues = // data source
let trainLabels = // data source

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x=trainValues, y=trainLabels, epochs=5)
```

### Node.js

```
let trainValues = // data source
let trainLabels = // data source

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [24], units: 24, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'softmax'}));
model.compile({
    loss: tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy,
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    metrics: ['accuracy']
});

trainValues = tf.tensor2d(trainValues);
trainLabels = tf.tensor1d(trainLabels);

await model.fit(trainValues, trainLabels, {
    epochs: 5
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second dense layers seem to have a different number of units (`2` in python, `1` in JavaScript).

In addition, your loss functions are different (`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in python, `softmaxCrossEntropy` in JavaScript). Instead of providing one of the `tf.losses.*` functions, you can simply pass a string here (as defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/blob/d086a5d014b2f74ec498b044b6127e57f5c83070/src/metrics.ts#L257)).

To have an identical model in JavaScript the code should look like this:

```js
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [24], units: 24, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}));
model.compile({
    loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    metrics: ['accuracy']
});
```

I'm assuming that the number of input units is `24` and that you correctly handled the data.